# Trying to implement css animation to morph a div background to a circular button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm setting contact2 as the same size as contact and displaying its position as absolute, with z-index -1, you can see in the design images what I'm trying to achieve

Desired Output (Design)

[image]

Desired Output (Design)
[image]

I'm trying to do this through javascript by assigning a class on onmouseover over the circle, and this class will do the animation, and  onmouseout I'm trying to reverse this.
but the morph is doing it into an oval and is not lining up with the circle.

```js
function minimize(a) {
  let ss = document.styleSheets;
  var x = document.getElementById("contact2");
  //x.classList.add('animate');
  //x.classList.add("animate");
  //x.className += "animate";
  x.classList.add("animate");
}

function maximize(a) {
  let ss = document.styleSheets;
  var x = document.getElementById("contact2");
  x.classList.remove('animate');

}
```

```css
.animate {
  animation-name: stretch;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes stretch {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    border-radius: 90%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.1);
    border-radius: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <div id="contact2" class="contact2"> </div>
  <div class="title">Do you have an exciting project?</div>
  <div class="talk">
    <a href="">
      <div class="square" onmouseover="minimize(this)" onmouseout="maximize(this)">Talk to me</div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it into a [mcve]

Comment: So why have a div in an anchor?

Comment: Also you are missing something in the contact2 div to give any effect

Comment: @mplungjan i need the circle to be clickable